# Looking for a proof of a distribution operator property.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

$u(x)$ is the step function and $T_u(x)$ be the distribution defined by

$$\forall \varphi \in D, 
\langle T_u , \varphi  \rangle
= \lim_{\epsilon \to  0} \left (\varphi(0) \ln(\epsilon)  + \int^{+ \infty } _ {\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} dx  \right )$$

In the sense of distributions, Prove  $\forall \varphi \in D$

$$ \langle (u(x) Ln(x))', \varphi \rangle
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left  (  \varphi(\epsilon)\ln (\epsilon ) + \int^{+ \infty}_{\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} dx  \right )  $$

---

**Try 1**

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle  (u(t) Ln(t) ) ' , \varphi\rangle 
                 &= \langle u'(t) ln(x)+ ln'(x) u(t) , \varphi \rangle
               \\&= \langle u'(t) ln(x) , \varphi \rangle
                              +\langle ln'(x) u(t) , \varphi \rangle
              \\&= \langle \delta(t) ln(x) , \varphi\rangle
                              +\langle u(t)/x , \varphi \rangle
              \\&= ln(0)\varphi(0) +  \int^{+\infty}_{0} \varphi(x) /x dx
\end{aligned} $$

and I just want to say that

$$ln(0)\varphi(0) +  \int^{+\infty}_{0} \varphi(x) /x dx= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left  (  \varphi(\epsilon)\ln (\epsilon ) + \int^{+ \infty}_{\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} dx  \right ) $$

**Anything wrong,thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that differentiating distributions in this manner generates things like $\delta(x) \ln x$, and how do you define the action of that object on an arbitrary test function? Instead, going strictly by definition,
$$((u(x) \ln x)', \phi) = - (u(x) \ln x, \phi') =
-\int_0^\infty \phi'(x) \ln x dx =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \Big( -\phi(x) \ln x \Big\rvert_{x = \epsilon}^\infty +
 \underbrace {\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac {\phi(x)} x dx}_{= I_\epsilon} \Big) =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} ( \phi(\epsilon) \ln \epsilon + I_\epsilon ) = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} ( (\phi(0) + O(\epsilon)) \ln \epsilon + I_\epsilon ) =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} ( \phi(0) \ln \epsilon + I_\epsilon ).$$